# JTextField: Change the foreground color and save the content

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, foreground

I have a frame with some `JTextFields` for the user insert some values.
When the window is opened, the text fields have written, in gray, what the user should write in that container, like "value in seconds"...

I want to change the color of those letters (I think it is the foreground) to dark when the user starts to write in the `JTextFields`, and save to a `String` what is written by the user.

Comment: To save the content written by a user just use `getText()`

To change the color of the font when the user writes just use an `OnClick` event and change the color

Comment: This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10506789/how-to-display-faint-gray-ghost-text-in-a-jtextfield/10507193#10507193

Comment: I would use a `FocusListener` and not an `OnClickListener` because you can easily handle the focus-loss event too that way.

Answer (score 3):

For the colour change you have to implement a `FocusListener` which sets the foreground with `setForeground()`. If you want to have a String of the current content of the `JTextField` you can achieve this with a `DocumentListener` to the underlying `Document`.

See this code as an example (I use blue and red for the colour and store the Text value of `tf` in the `String` content):

```
JTextField tf = new JTextFiedl();
tf.addFocusListener(new FocusListener()
{
    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe)
    {
        tf.setForeground(INACTIVE_COLOUR);
    }

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent fe)
    {
        tf.setForeground(ACTIVE_COLOUR);
    }
});
```

A full working example is here:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class TF
{
    private final Color ACTIVE_COLOUR = Color.BLUE;
    private final Color INACTIVE_COLOUR = Color.RED;

    private String content; //text of the text field is stored here

    private JTextField tf;
    private JTextField lbl;

    public TF()
    {
        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Window");

        tf = new JTextField("Hint");
        lbl = new JTextField("click here to change focus");

        tf.setForeground(ACTIVE_COLOUR);

        setListeners();

        mainFrame.add(tf, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        mainFrame.add(lbl, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        mainFrame.pack();
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void setListeners()
    {
        tf.addFocusListener(new FocusListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe)
            {
                tf.setForeground(INACTIVE_COLOUR);
            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent fe)
            {
                tf.setForeground(ACTIVE_COLOUR);
            }
        });

        tf.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent de)
            {
                content = tf.getText();
            }

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent de)
            {
                content = tf.getText();
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent de)
            {
                content = tf.getText();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TF tf = new TF();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See [Text Prompt](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/11/29/text-prompt/) for another approach.