# set hidden text into JTextfield in java

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I'm trying to create one search toolbar that appears inside the letters hidden stick. when I press the hidden letters that when the bar disappears and there's no hiding the letters that appear. I've tried to capture events keyPressed entering the search bar, but I do not really feel comfortable with that way. if anyone has a better way, I hope everyone helps do.cam Thanks!

photo illustration

[image]

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10506789/how-to-display-faint-gray-ghost-text-in-a-jtextfield

Comment: Why don't you feel comfortable with that way?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Text Prompt](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/11/29/text-prompt/).

You can control when the prompt disappears. You can also control the color and style of prompt.

The `Text Prompt` uses a DocumentListener and a FocusListener to determine when the prompt should be displayed.

You can use the default settings with a single line of code:

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
TextPrompt tp7 = new TextPrompt("First Name", textField);
```