# How can I clear the textfield when it is enabled?

Tags: java, swing, textfield, jtextfield

The textfield is disabled and with text.

When I touch a button, the textfield will be enabled for editing.

However, I would like to textfield to be cleared when enabled.

One constraint is that I can;t add any other listener to the button.

Is there anyone can answer my question?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could attach a property listener and listen for the "enabled" event

```
field.addPropertyChangeListener("enabled", listener);
```

This doesn't require you mess around with the field at all...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have tried
  textField.addPropertyChangeListener("enabled", new PropertyChangeListener() {

   public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
    text.setText("");
                                panel.revalidate();
    
   }
  });

it seems that the program didn't run into the listener when the textfield is enabled.

Comment: Problem solved!!
field.addPropertyChangeListener("editable", listener);
Thx!!

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

**Inside the button listener that enables the textfield**, after enabling statement,just add `mytext.setText("");`

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify more. I cannot do anything about the button.

Comment: Can you please elaborate, what do u mean by "I cannot do anything about the button"

Comment: The constraint is that I cannot do anything on the button.
including
adding mytext.setText(""); in the button listener

Answer (score 0):

check here, Here is the answer of your question. You just need some modifications...

[Java JTextField with input hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738966/java-jtextfield-with-input-hint)

Comment: I'm sorry. I am not having a listener that listner to the value change of the textfield.
I would like to clear the textfield when it is being enabled by the button.
And I can't do anything on Button is the constraint.