# Adding JavaFX TextField to JPanel

Tags: java, swing, javafx, jpanel

I have a `JPanel cPanel`, and a `TextField resultField` imported from JDK 8's `javafx.scene.control.TextField`. 
Now I want to `cPanel.add(resultField,BorderLayout.NORTH)`, Eclipse give me an error:

```
The method add(String, Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (TextField, String)
```

How do I add `resultField` to `cPanel` properly?

Comment: JPanel is a swing component. It would make more sense to add a  swing JTextField than the JavaFX TextField.

Comment: @willshackford thanks. That does make sense. I wanted to add prompt text to resultField, but JTextField doesn't support prompt text

Comment: Then , Its better to switch to javafx instead of using java swing.

Comment: SwingLabs SwingX library has `Prompt` (and `Buddy`) support as demonstrated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22396282/how-to-set-text-like-placeholder-in-jtextfield-in-swing/22396303#22396303)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but JTextField doesn't support prompt text

You can use the [Text Prompt](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/11/29/text-prompt/) class.

I allows you to specify a prompt that is displayed when the text field is empty. As soon as you type text the prompt is removed.

The prompt is actually a JLabel so you can customize the font, forground etc..:

```
JTextField tf7 = new JTextField(10);
TextPrompt tp7 = new TextPrompt("First Name", tf7);
tp7.setForeground( Color.RED );
```

Comment: Ok that's pretty good. I wonder why it is not a part of Swing.

Comment: @DylanChen, well it was added to JavaFX, but Swing is no longer being developed.

Comment: @DylanChen Prompt support is kind of a "newish" thing in UI's, Swing was designed by back before 2000, with only a few additions been added in the early years

Answer (score 2):

You can Download **swingx-core-1.6.2.jar** and use it to make swing Text Fields Prompt text.

```
    PromptSupport.setPrompt("User ID", userNameField);
    PromptSupport.setFontStyle(Font.BOLD, userNameField);
    PromptSupport.setForeground(Color.BLACK, userNameField);
    PromptSupport.setFocusBehavior(PromptSupport.FocusBehavior.HIDE_PROMPT,
            userNameField);
```

Download it from here :http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/swingx/swingx-core-1.6.2.jar.zip

Comment: It's now up to [1.6.4](https://java.net/downloads/swingx/releases/swingx-all-1.6.4.jar)