# Java/Swing - Set title for TextField

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextfield

I could not find any class to set a title for TextField. Therefore, I decided to make one. My question is really simple.

Do I really need to include JFrame in my class or maybe there is a different way to accomplish this problem.

Here is my GUI class.

```
public GUI() {  
    JFrame f = new JFrame("MyLibrary");
    JTextField tf = new JTextField();
    
    tf.setBounds(50, 50, 400, 30);
    tf.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16));
    FieldTitle ft = new FieldTitle(f, tf, "Book title");
    
    f.add(tf);
    f.setSize(1280, 720);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setLayout(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

And here is my FieldTitle class.

```
public FieldTitle(JFrame f, Component c, String title) {
    JLabel l = new JLabel(title);
    
    l.setBounds(c.getBounds().x, c.getBounds().y - 20, c.getWidth(), 20);
    
    f.add(l);
}
```

Thank you for your time and effort. Have a great day!

Comment: You could consider having a look at the `PromptSupport` found in the SwingX library, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22396282/how-to-set-text-like-placeholder-in-jtextfield-in-swing/22396303#22396303)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a null layout. Don't use setBounds().

Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. You can easily use a `JPanel` with a `BoxLayout`:

1. Create a `JPanel` and set the layout to a vertical BoxLayout
2. Create and add the `JLabel` to the panel
3. Create and and the `JTextField` to the panel
4. Add the panel to the frame.

Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information. You will find a working example that shows how to create a frame with a panel using a BoxLayout.