# How to make a JLabel/JTextField/JTextArea translucent?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jcomponent

How can I make a JLabel translucent? I want to display a translucent label/text-field containing some text over a JTextfield so as to suggest the words to be typed by the user.

Comment: For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22396282/how-to-set-text-like-placeholder-in-jtextfield-in-swing/22396303#22396303) (and [SwingX](https://github.com/arotenberg/swingx))

Comment: Do you mean you want to something like "auto complete"?

Comment: Maybe [Text Prompt](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/11/29/text-prompt/) will help.