# Is there a Java equivalent to the HTML title attribute?

Tags: java, swing, title

You can put a `title` attribute on any HTML element. Usually, the content of the title attribute will be displayed if the element is pointed by the user for about one second. It is a very convenient way to give help to users that may need some. Here is how it looks like:
[image: Title example]

I am looking for a **java swing** build-in feature imitating this behavior. If it does not exist, can you provide a set of good practices to implement it?

Note: I am **not** looking for the HTML5 `placeholder` attribute equivalent that can be found on this post: [Java JTextField with input hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738966/java-jtextfield-with-input-hint)

Comment: Yes there is. It's called [ToolTip text](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tooltip.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want the [JToolTip](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JToolTip.html) class.