# How to add prompt text/ hint to a text field in Java

Tags: java, textfield

Instead of setting up 3 TextFields on a Stage that collect first, second and last names, I'd like to have just one in which a user can enter all his/ her names. I think my form will look simpler, less clustered, therefore less complicated for my users.

I was on some web page some time back and saw an implementation of the above this way:

> > The text field when blank shows three parts hinting first, second and
> >        last name. When initially on forcus, only the first name hint
> >        dissapeared, but the others, second and last remained. Then when
> >        you're done entering the first name and press spacebar, the second
> >        name dissapears and now only the last name hint shows. The same will
> >        go for last name after entering the second name.

All text dissapears when the hint is set as `new TextField("hint");`.

Is there a way to go about it without having all the hints dissapear on focus?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738966/java-jtextfield-with-input-hint

Comment: you 3 text-fields without gap

Comment: Take a look at [SwingX's `PromptSupport` API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20578568/java-swing-listen-an-action-in-a-text-field-of-a-form/20578601#20578601)

Comment: @RafaelOsipov FYI, that has now been incorporated in SwingX.  It might be better to direct people their instead

Comment: Funny, really should have checked first, what framework you using?  AWT, Swing, SWT, GWT, JavaFX?

Comment: @madhawa priyashantha's idea worked good. Thanks MadProgrammer and everyone else for your ideas. I'm using JavaFx, but I'd have adopted any implementation, and tried to make it work.